# Paypal transaction inside a modal?

Tags: javascript, html, paypal

Is there a way to show the Paypal transaction window within a modal window?  For example, we currently have users clicking on the "Pay Now" button, and I can either get it to display in a new window/tab so they can do their transaction, or I am able to have it display in a popup.  However, I tried to push the Paypal data into either a div or iframe within a modal and can't seem to get it to work--it forces a reload of the page and goes to Paypal instead.  I want the page to remain static, and not forward the user to Paypal--instead, I want that Paypal window to show in a modal.  Is this even possible?  I'm thinking not, but thought I'd try asking...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nope, it's a security issue, paypal wants to maintain control so their users can be sure they are dealing with them directly

Comment: I thought so, thanks for the quick answer.  Will give you a green checkmark in about 10 mins (the system doesn't let me do it so quickly)

Comment: Maybe it is an option when your users do reoccuring transactions: You can use PayPal Pre-Approvals and you get completely rid of all PayPal pages.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Express Checkout:
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECGettingStarted