# PayPal Adaptive Payments in modal window?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Paypal adaptive payments (chained payments) payment flow in a lightbox/modal window?

Is it possible?

Found this: [PayPal chained payments using Website Payments Pro (or similar)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690007/paypal-chained-payments-using-website-payments-pro-or-similar)

Any hints? Or workarounds?

Mike

Comment: I'm just wondering the same thing... found this here 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397815/paypal-transaction-inside-a-modal

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Paypal modal box and chained payments together. You have to set the chained payment in the pay request. For example, if you want to test a chained payment in the sandbox, the pay request URL must be like this:

```
$URL=  'https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay?actionType=PAY
    &receiverList.receiver(0).email=primary@email.com
    &receiverList.receiver(0).amount=50
    &receiverList.receiver(0).primary=true
    &receiverList.receiver(1).email=chained@email.com
    &receiverList.receiver(1).amount=40
    &currencyCode=EUR
    &cancelUrl=http://cancel_url.com
    &returnUrl=http://return_url.com
    &requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US';
```

You can have 1-5 secondary receivers.

Paypal will response with a key that you use for other API operations. With this key you must launch the modal window.

Take a look to the *Paypal Adaptive Payments Developer Guide*, section "Embedded Payment Flow Presentations".